# How to display a list of movies from an API using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to display a list of movies title based on the year the user searches for. I dont need to loop all the pages, the results of the first page is enough.  I really don't know what am I doing wrong that when I click search the app crashes.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Movies = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState(false);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
  const [year, setYear] = useState("");
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  const searchMovies = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSearch(true);
    const url = `https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies?Year=${year}`;
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      setMessage(null);
      setMovies(data); // needs check
      setSearch(false);
    } catch (err) {
      setMessage("Unexpected Error happened");
      setSearch(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form action="" onSubmit={searchMovies}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter a year"
          name="year"
          value={year}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setYear(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <button type="submit">Searc</button>
      </form>

      <div className="movies-container">
        {search && !message ? (
          <span>Loading...</span>
        ) : message ? (
          <div className="message"> {message} </div>
        ) : (
          movies.map((movie) => <li key={movie.imdbID}> Title: {movie.Title}</li>)
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Movies;
```

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Whats is the error message ?

Comment: @MarcCharpentier 
I get TypeError: movies.map is not a function

Comment: @Cybershadow Please check the screenshot I just added to the question.

Comment: try ```setMovies(data.data)``` instead of ```setMovies(data)```

Comment: @MarcCharpentier You're amazing Marc, thank you very much! I can't believe it was just that. Do you mind telling me how did you figure that out?

Comment: I saw the json returned from the URL you put above, you needed the data in the array of objects ```data```. Can you accept my answer below ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure `movies` is an array,

Check the value of `movies` by adding a console log

```
const data = await response.json();
console.log("data ", data);
setMovies(data);
```

And i saw the json of your API think you need to put `setMovies(data.data);` instead of `setMovies(data);`